Why is the link not clickable with nodemailer?
I am using nodemailer package with Brevo SMTP in my backend app and I am trying to send an email from where the user should be able to reset their password. The email is sent but the link is not clickable:

And the element looks like this in the console:

I set a dummy URL just to see if it works and if I click that link from the href attribute it redirects me to the google page:
var link = "http://google.com";
const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.RESET_PASSWORD_EMAIL,
    to: email,
    subject: 'Password Reset',
    html: '<p>You are receiving this email because you have requested the reset of the password for your account.</p><br />' +
          '<p>Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:</p>' +
          '<a href=\"' + link.toString() + '\">Reset password</a><br />' +
          '<p>If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.</p>'
    };


#1 If the reset password link is real,  obfuscate it in your image. #2 Try with other several inboxs like: gmail, outlook, yahoo, etc #3 Are you using antivirus or something similar?

If the link is clickable when it points to https://google.com but not if you use your own custom link, the culprit is probably your link, because nodemailer surely does not alter your email-content, only brevo does replace links with a redirection service for purpose of click tracking. You can try disabling this feature, so your original link will remain and then check if that is clickable. Alternatively, you can try to copy the url of the link and paste it directly in the browser and then inspect the response code

And what client are you using to display the mail. Maybe this client just blocks your url?

@JRichardsz The link is not real, just used for testing. I send the mail to a Yahoo address and try to access the link from there. No antivirus.

@derpirscher It's not that google.com works and my link doesn't. Both of them work if i take them from the "href" attribute. The thing is that for either of them the redirection is not working when clicking on the "Reset password" button.

If the the link per se is working, but it's just not clickable, I'd suspect it's an issue with your client (for instance it might not allow links going to the click-tracking of brevo) ... Because as I said, nodemailer doesn't alter in any way your HTML body.
